# Android app saving and storing images in gallery?

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery

How can I save pictures taken by a camera through my app into my device's gallery?

The problem is that the app currently crashes after taking a picture and can only save a single image in the directory specified. 
Am i right in assuming the app is crashing because it doesn't know what to do after saving a file? How might i go about rectifying this problem, anything after the return statement is "unreachable code".

The code:

```
public class Activity_Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        public static final int cameraData = 1;

        ImageButton ib;
        ImageView iv;
        Intent i;
        Bitmap bmp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
                initialise();
        }

        private void initialise() {
                iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPicReturn);
                ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);

                ib.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.ibTakePic:
                        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        //
                        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri());              
                        //
                        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
                        break;
                }
        }
        //
        private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/TradeIt");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();  
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            return uriSavedImage;


        }
        //
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);


                }

        }

}
```

logcat

```
W/dalvikvm(919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d7d930) 
03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.hyperlocal.tradeit/com.hyperlocal.tradeit.Activity_Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
```

Comment: posting the logcat would help

Comment: @DigCamara
03-07 00:00:24.694: W/dalvikvm(919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d7d930)

03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.hyperlocal.tradeit/com.hyperlocal.tradeit.Activity_Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-07 00:00:24.704: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to increment a variable and save it and add it to your file name to make more pictures when you get the Uri and for the pictures to show up in your gallery do this:

```
   sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" +    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

if you dont sentBroadcast like this after you take the picture the gallery wont be updated until the next time the phone is turned on